# How to implement search in the array of object using javascript

Tags: javascript

Need to implement the search the value includes or not in the array of object, if exists only filter the particular object to display. Here is my solution

```
let data = [
        {
            "name": "Human Capital Management (HCM)",
            "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
            "listingType": "integration",
            "connectors": [
                {
                    "name": "oracle",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "Oracle",
                },
                {
                    "name": "greenhouse",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "greenhouse",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Applicant tracking system (ATS)",
            "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
            "listingType": "integration",
            "connectors": [
                {
                    "name": "HiBob",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "HiBob",
                },
                {
                    "name": "greenhouse",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "greenhouse",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Search value is

```
let searchVal = 'Greenhouse'
```

filtering function

```
let responseData = []
        
        await Promise.all(data.map(async (value)=> {
            if(value.name.includes(searchVal)) {
                responseData.push(value)
            }

            if(value.listingType.includes(searchVal)) {
                responseData.push(value)
            }

            if(Array.isArray(value.connectors)) {
                let connectors = await filterConnection(value.connectors, searchVal)
                if(Array.isArray(connectors) && connectors.length > 0) {
                    responseData.push({
                        ...value,
                        connectors
                    })
                }
            }
        }))

        return responseData
```

Need to implement the search function with more efficient code, kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: You can use filter() instead of map() , and toLowerCase() function to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: Is `filterConnection` a function that actually needs to be async? If not then there is no need for any of the await or promises. Please post a [mcve], preferably using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

```
let data = [
    {
        "name": "Human Capital Management (HCM)",
        "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
        "listingType": "integration",
        "connectors": [
            {
                "name": "oracle",
                "description": "our global platform",
                "companyName": "Oracle",
            },
            {
                "name": "greenhouse",
                "description": "our global platform",
                "companyName": "greenhouse",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Applicant tracking system (ATS)",
        "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
        "listingType": "integration",
        "connectors": [
            {
                "name": "HiBob",
                "description": "our global platform",
                "companyName": "HiBob",
            },
            {
                "name": "greenhouse",
                "description": "our global platform",
                "companyName": "greenhouse",
            }
        ]
    },
];

let searchVal = 'Greenhouse';

let responseData = data.filter(value => {
    // Check if any of the properties match the search value
    if (value.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }

    if (value.listingType.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())) {
        return true;
    }

    // Check if any connector matches the search value
    if (Array.isArray(value.connectors)) {
        let connectors = value.connectors.filter(connector =>
            connector.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase()) ||
            connector.companyName.toLowerCase().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())
        );

        if (connectors.length > 0) {
            value.connectors = connectors; // Update connectors with filtered array
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
});

console.log(responseData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively construct a new data array with matching string properties in objects regardless of data structure.

Given code provided in the question it's not clear whether for example if `listingType` matches, should be `connectors` filtered as well or not...

```js
const hasString = (obj, str, regex = new RegExp(str, 'i')) => {
  
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) return obj.reduce((r, item) => {
    const out = hasString(item, str, regex);
    (Array.isArray(out) ? out.length : out) && r.push(out);
    return r;
  }, []);
  
  if(obj && typeof obj === 'object'){
    let matches = false;
    const out = {};
    for(const k in obj){
      const r = hasString(obj[k], str, regex);
      if(Array.isArray(r)){
        if(r.length) matches = true;
        out[k] = r;
      }else {
        if(r) matches = true;
        out[k] = obj[k];
      }
    }
    if(matches) return out;
  } else if(typeof obj === 'string' && regex.test(obj)){
    return true;
  }
}

const result = hasString(data, 'Greenhouse');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
let data = [
        {
            "name": "Human Capital Management (HCM)",
            "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
            "listingType": "integration",
            "connectors": [
                {
                    "name": "oracle",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "Oracle",
                },
                {
                    "name": "greenhouse",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "greenhouse",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Applicant tracking system (ATS)",
            "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
            "listingType": "integration",
            "connectors": [
                {
                    "name": "HiBob",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "HiBob",
                },
                {
                    "name": "greenhouse",
                    "description": "our global platform",
                    "companyName": "greenhouse",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple function. I have included one more object in the data, which doesn't have `Greenhouse` as a value for testing purposes. I have used `map` function along with `forEach` to check if the objects include the value 'Greenhouse' or not.

For each object in the data, first, all the values in the object, including that of the nested objects, are collected in an array and checked against the `searchVal`. If a match is found, the object is returned. (p.s -
The code is written assuming that there is nested array with objects)

```js
let searchVal = 'Greenhouse';

data.map(
  (obj) => {
    let d = [];
    let c = Object.values(obj);
    (c.forEach((ele) => {
      if (typeof(ele) == "object") {
        ele.forEach((x) => d.push(Object.values(x)));
      } else {
        d.push(ele);
      }
      if (d.flat().includes(searchVal.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log(obj)
      }
    }))
  }
)
```

```html
<script>
let data = [{
    "name": "Human Capital Management (HCM)",
    "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
    "listingType": "integration",
    "connectors": [{
        "name": "oracle",
        "description": "our global platform",
        "companyName": "Oracle",
      },
      {
        "name": "greenhouse",
        "description": "our global platform",
        "companyName": "greenhouse",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Applicant tracking system (ATS)",
    "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
    "listingType": "integration",
    "connectors": [{
        "name": "HiBob",
        "description": "our global platform",
        "companyName": "HiBob",
      },
      {
        "name": "greenhouse",
        "description": "our global platform",
        "companyName": "greenhouse",
      }
    ]
  }, ,
  {
    "name": "VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVvvvvvv",
    "description": "data entry with automatic data syncing capabilities.",
    "listingType": "integration",
    "connectors": [{
        "name": "HiBob",
        "description": "our global platform",
        "companyName": "HiBob",
      },
      {
        "name": "house",
        "description": "our global platform",
        "companyName": "house",
      }
    ]
  },
]
</script>
```